# How to sort NSDictionary using millisecond (Time format)?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, sorting, dictionary

I have a Dictionary of format [Int:Any] I have bunch of key value pairs in it. I want to sort out the dictionary using the millisecond time format

```
[169887: ["noti_type": 0, "project_name": "Design Project", "eventCount": 6, "author_pic": " /file/download/profile$2348d4f21095a01cc16a8ad9bf08f966.jpg", "canvas_name": "Design Reference #31 : Windows in NYC", "lastUpdatedAt": 1513585053629, "author_name": "Jake Kyung "],


173865: ["noti_type": 0, "project_name": "BeeCanvas DEV", "eventCount": 13, "author_pic": " &&&&   /file/download/profile$80bbc9731a859d4e083df0df8044bcde.jpg &&&&   /file/download/profile$2348d4f21095a01cc16a8ad9bf08f966.jpg", "canvas_name": "Android Release note", "lastUpdatedAt": 1513307315308, "author_name": " &&&&  Sukho Bu  &&&&  Jake Kyung "]
```

I have a bunch of these kind of values in my Dictionary. I want to sort them using the lastUpdatedAt value which is `1513585053629` millisecond format.

I have gone through some posts which said this is possible if I can use a NSDate,

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey: @"dateOfInfo" ascending: NO];
NSArray *sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
```

[sortDescriptor release];

But I was just wondering if I could achieve this directly using the millisecond format instead of converting to NSDate ?

Comment: The date in milliseconds is a **number**. You can sort the dictionary according to it easily.

Comment: How can I specify this particular key value pair, to sort my entire Dictionary depending on values of that particular key value pair ?

Comment: A dictionary is unordered by definition. You can't sort it.

Answer (score 1):

This is just demo for understanding..

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict1 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [dict1 setObject:@"Design Project" forKey:@"project_name"];
    [dict1 setObject:@"1513585053629" forKey:@"lastUpdatedAt"];

    NSMutableDictionary *dict2 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [dict2 setObject:@"BeeCanvas DEV" forKey:@"project_name"];
    [dict2 setObject:@"1513307315308" forKey:@"lastUpdatedAt"];

    NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [arr addObject:dict1];
    [arr addObject:dict2];
    NSLog(@"original array = %@",arr);
```

you can give directly key name in sort descriptor.

```
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey: @"lastUpdatedAt" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortedArray = [arr sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
    NSLog(@"sorted array = %@",sortedArray);
```

**Output:-**

```
sorted array = (
        {
        lastUpdatedAt = 1513307315308;
        "project_name" = "BeeCanvas DEV";
    },
        {
        lastUpdatedAt = 1513585053629;
        "project_name" = "Design Project";
    }
)
```

Comment: @SritejaC if you are output is different not like above then tell

Comment: Thanks for the input, actually I have taken a lot of thinking and changed my model so that now last updated is my key and sorting of keys is very easy. `let sortedKeysDict = NotificationModel.unreadDict.sorted{ $0.key > $1.key }`